# Kohana 3.0.x ORM: Read additional columns in pivot tables

Tags: orm, kohana

I'm using Kohana v3 and ORM, I have two models, `Model_A` and `Model_B` related by "has_many" through a pivot table, which has an additional column. I can save data in that column in the pivot table using the third parameter of the `add()` function, but I can't figure out how to read that column using ORM.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a Model that is based on that pivot table if you want to access that additional column, let say we name it `Model_A_B`.

```
class Model_A_B extends ORM {

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'A' => array(),
        'B' => array()
    );

}
```

Then, if `$a` is an instance of `Model_A` and `$b` is an instance of `Model_B`, we get the `Model_A_B` instance by calling:

```
$ab = ORM::factory('A_B', array('A_id' => $a, 'B_id' => $b));

if ($ab->loaded()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You're showing to retrieve a value from a pivot but can you also show a way to initially set the value in the pivot?

Comment: where would you store that model? ...models/a/b.php ?

Comment: @Brenden: Yes, models/a/b.php