# Kohana 3 ORM: How to get data from pivot table? and all other tables for that matter

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

I am trying to use ORM to access data stored, in three mysql tables 'users', 'items', and a pivot table for the many-many relationship: 'user_item'

I followed the guidance from [Kohana 3.0.x ORM: Read additional columns in pivot tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946357/kohana-3-orm-read-additional-columns-in-pivot-tables)

and tried

```
    $user = ORM::factory('user',1);
    $user->items->find_all();

    $user_item = ORM::factory('user_item', array('user_id' => $user, 'item_id' => $user->items));
    if ($user_item->loaded()) {
        foreach ($user_item as $pivot) {
            print_r($pivot);
        }    
    }
```

But I get the SQL error:

> "Unknown column 'user_item.id' in
>   'order clause' [ SELECT `user_item`.*
>   FROM `user_item` WHERE `user_id` = '1'
>   AND `item_id` = '' ORDER BY
>   `user_item`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1 ]"

Which is clearly erroneous because Kohana is trying to order the elements by a column which doesn't exist: user_item.id.  This id doesnt exist because the primary keys of this pivot table are the foreign keys of the two other tables, 'users' and 'items'.

Trying to use:

```
$user_item = ORM::factory('user_item', array('user_id' => $user, 'item_id' => $user->items))
                    ->order_by('item_id', 'ASC');
```

Makes no difference, as it seems the `order_by()` or any sql queries are ignored if the second argument of the factory is given.

Another obvious error with that query is that the item_id = '', when it should contain all the elements.

So my question is **how can I get access to the data stored in the pivot table**, and actually **how can I get access to the all items held by a particular user** as I even had problems with that?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you do a `$user->items->find_all()`? Maybe you forgot to include a `foreach` statement (or similar) to iterate over the results of the `find_all()` method.

Answer (score 2):

By default, all of Kohana's ORM models expect the table's primary key to be 'id.'  You need to set $_primary_key in your model to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`$user_item = ORM::factory('user_item', array('user_id' => $user, 'item_id' => $user->items));`

I think you need to provide a single item_id value for this to work, not an array of objects.

Also, to find all entries for a single user you should be able to do this:
`$user_items = ORM::factory('user_item', array('user_id' => $user));`

Does that answer your question?