# Kohana pivot tables with additional columns not loading

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana

I'm using Kohana v3 with Database and ORM.
I found a nice question which help me add and read additional columns in pivot tables:
[Kohana 3.0.x ORM: Read additional columns in pivot tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946357/kohana-3-0-x-orm-read-additional-columns-in-pivot-tables)

I got 2 pivot table with additional column. One of those works perfectly but I'm stuck in the unknown with the second.

Got 2 tables, applications and partners plus my pivot table with the next ORM models:

```
class Model_Application extends ORM
{

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'partners'=>array(
            'model'=>'partner',
            'through'=>'partners_applications',
            )
        );
}

//AND

class Model_Partner extends ORM
{

protected $_has_many = array(
    'applications' => array(
        'model'=>'application',
        'through'=>'partners_applications',
        )
    );

}

//plus my pivot table ORM model

class Model_Partners_applications extends ORM
{

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
            'partner' => array(),
            'application' => array()
        );
}
```

When I try to get

```
$instance = ORM::factory('partners_applications',array('partner_id' => $this->partner,'application_id' =>   $this->application))->find();
```

Kohana keep saying :

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Partners_applications' not found
```

I've triple checked Model name constructions but I can't find the error.
In Kohana environment debug part, my two firsts models are loaded but not the pivot table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Should be `ORM::factory('partners_application')`, in Kohana ORM always expects singular form ;)

Comment: I think plurial form fits for many to many relationship in Kohana. Anyway, Singular form for partner and/or application send me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Model_Partners_applications should be inside   application/classes/model/partners/applications.php

Comment: So application/classes/model/partners/applications.php contains :
`class Model_Partners_applications extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name  = 'partners_applications';

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
            'partner' => array(),
            'application' => array()
        );
}`
It's not working for me, still the same error and the new class is not even loaded...