# Add custom field to a many-to-many relationship in Kohana 2

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I have 2 models: Home and User.
A user can has many homes, and a home can have many users.

The table homes_users (the relation table) has these fields: User_id, home_id, date

I need to create a relation between the X user and the Y home, created in Z date (just a date)
The code i'm using is:

```
$user = ORM::factory('User',$user_id);
$user->home_id = $home_id;
$user->date = date("Y-m-d");
$user->save();
```

But the system says "The property home_id doesn't exists in User_model"

I can add a home to a user, but i cant add a home to a user **CREATED IN Z DATE.**

How can i do that????

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a model for your pivot table, so you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946357/kohana-3-0-x-orm-read-additional-columns-in-pivot-tables). Then in pivot model you will add: `protected $_created_column = array('column' => 'date', 'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s');` where 'date' is your column name.

Comment: I have to create the Model for my Pivot table to use 
$user->add('home', $home, array('date' => time()));
$home = ORM::factory('home', array('name' => 'user'));
???

Comment: No, that is option where you do not have to create the model. For the first option you must create model, it is up to you to choose.

Comment: Great, but i made a mistake, its a many-to-many relationship between user and home models.

And maybe that code won't work anymore
$user->add('home', $home, array('date' => time()));
$home = ORM::factory('home', array('name' => 'user'));

Comment: I tried this:
$user->add(ORM::factory('home',array("home_id"=>$home_id,"created" => date("Y-m-d"))));

but doesn't work too

Comment: I'm using kohana 2.x, so the method ADD accepts just one parameter (a model). Is there any other solution?